# Blazor Client Update Model Form Pre-population

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor

I'm building a CRUD application in Blazor WebAssembly, and on the Update View I have:

**UpdateForecast.razor**

```
@page "/forecast/update/{Id}"
@using System.Text.Json
@using System.Text.Json.Serialization
@using WeatherBA.Shared.Dtos
@using WeatherBA.Shared.Responses
@inject HttpClient Http
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<PageTitle>Update forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Update forecast</h1>

@if (forecast != null)
{

    <EditForm Model="@forecast" OnValidSubmit="@SaveForecast">
        <table>

            <tr><label>Id:</label></tr>
            <tr><input type="text" @bind-value="forecast.Id"/></tr>

            <tr><label>Date:</label></tr>
            <tr><input type="text" @bind-value="forecast.Date"/></tr>

            <tr><label>Temperature:</label></tr>
            <tr><input type="text" @bind-value="forecast.TemperatureC"/></tr>

            <tr><label>Summary:</label></tr>
            <tr><input type="text" @bind-value="forecast.Summary"/></tr>

            <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </table>
    </EditForm>
} else
{
    <p>Loadnig...</p>
}


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    private ForecastDto? forecast = new ForecastDto();

    private CreateForecastCommandResponse? response = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecast =  await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<ForecastDto> ("api/Forecast" + Id); 
        //not filling form but but api return correct object
    }

    protected async Task SaveForecast()
    {
        //response = new CreateForecastCommandResponse();
        HttpResponseMessage frame =  await Http.PutAsJsonAsync("api/Forecast/" + Id, forecast);
        response = await frame.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<CreateForecastCommandResponse>();
        
        if(response.Success == true)
             NavManager.NavigateTo("/forecast/" + Id);   
    }
}
```

OnInitializedAsync() has to fetch the data and populate input fields with values of given object.

The problem is it doesn't. Any sugestions why can it be?

Comment: I recommend using InputText instead of input. Also put a @if(forecast != null) around your form to prevent binding to null.

Comment: I used as InputText instead input you said and form dissapeared :)

Comment: Wow. It was missing "/" character in the onf of ("api/forecast" + Id) in GetFromJsonAsync() method in OnInitializedAsync(). Without it Blazor tried to resolve client not server paths.

Comment: That would be why it stayed null... BTW Always check your browser console and network tab.

Comment: id maybe unknown at runtime, because it is a parameter.  Use on OnParametersSetAsync() . More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0